# Trying to add optional attributes to Google Shopping API

Tags: php, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I am not a programmer but have had a go at adding some optional content api attributes to existing code. So far, the output is empty even though the fields contain data.

I have edited the calling php file and its included file.

The optional attributes are:

```
color,sizes,multipack,ageGroup,gender,material
```

File run: `ProductsSample_orig.php`

Relevant code:

```
include_once('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/class.php');
require_once 'BaseSample.php';

private function createExampleProducts($offerIds) {
    $products = [];        

    foreach ($offerIds as $offerId) {
        //print_r($offerId);
        foreach($offerId as $offer) {
            // echo $offer['name'];
            //echo $offer['language'];
            $products[] = $this->createExampleProduct($offer['name'],$offer['products_id'],$offer['description'],$offer['color'],$offer['sizes'],$offer['multipack'],$offer['ageGroup'],$offer['gender'],$offer['material'],$offer['image_link'],$offer['sellprice'],$offer['team'],$offer['weight'],$offer['gtin'],$offer['country'],$offer['currency'],$offer['language'],$offer['prodlink'],'',$offer['availability'],$offer['categoryname']);
        }
    }
    return $products;
}

private function createExampleProduct($name,$team_id,$description,$color,$sizes,$multipack,$ageGroup,$gender,$material,$image,$priceselling,$brand,$weight,$gtin,$country,$currency,$language,$link,$delivery_cost,$availability,$category) {
 // print_r($offerId);
 // echo $priceselling;
 // echo "gtin for: ".$team_id." is :".$gtin;
$description=htmlentities($description);
$cat=utf8_encode($category);
//  echo $name."\n".$team_id."\n".$description."\n".$image."\n".$priceselling."\n".$brand."\n".$weight."\n".$gtin."\n".$country."\n".$currency."\n".$language."\n".$link."\n".$delivery_cost."\n".$availability."\n".$category;
//  die;   

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d");
$expires =date("c",  strtotime('+1 days', strtotime($timestamp)));
$product = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product();
//$offerd=$id['team_id'];
$product->setOfferId($team_id);
//$name=$id['name'];
$product->setTitle($name);
//$desc=$id['description'];
$product->setDescription($description);
$product->setColor($color);
$product->setSizes($sizes);
$product->setMultipack($multipack);
$product->setAgeGroup($ageGroup);
$product->setGender($gender);
$product->setMaterial($material);
$product->setLink($link);
$product->setImageLink($image);
$product->setBrand($brand);
$product->setContentLanguage($language);
$product->setTargetCountry($country);
$product->setChannel(self::CHANNEL);
$product->setAvailability($availability);
$product->setCondition('new');
$product->setGoogleProductCategory($cat);
$product->setexpirationDate($expires);
if(!empty($gtin)){
$product->setGtin($gtin);
}else{
    $product->setidentifierExists(FALSE);
}
$price = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price();
$price->setValue($priceselling);
$price->setCurrency($currency);
$product->setPrice($price);
/* $shippingPrice = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price();
$shippingPrice->setValue($delivery_cost);
$shippingPrice->setCurrency($currency);*/
/*  $shipping = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductShipping(); */
// $shipping->setPrice($shippingPrice);
/*  $shipping->setCountry($country); */
/* $shipping->setService('Standard shipping'); */
/* $product->setShipping(array($shipping)); */
$shippingWeight =
    new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductShippingWeight();
$shippingWeight->setValue($weight);
$shippingWeight->setUnit('grams');
$product->setShippingWeight($shippingWeight);
```

=====================================================================

class.php

includes code:

```
$dbpro="SELECT DISTINCT'
vp.virtuemart_product_id AS products_id,

vp.colour AS color,
vp.size AS sizes,
vp.multipack AS multipack,
vp.age_group AS ageGroup,
vp.gender AS gender,
vp.material AS material,
```

============================================================

Expected results:

Log output for 1 product which has a Size of 5cm

```
Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product Object
(

...

[sizeSystem] => 
[sizeType] => 
[sizes] => 

should be:

sizes = 5cm
```

Should sizeSystem & sizeType have associated fields + variables?

I should add that, when, run, no error messages are produced, just no content in the newly added attributes.

Thank You

Comment: I think sizes, sizeSystem and sizeType are only for dresses. Because Google is only allowing attributes like regular, oversize, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that info, Ivion.

Comment: Am I asking the wrong question?